# Does my husband need to visit a court to file for divorce?

Tags: nikah, talaq

I've been married to my husband for 1 year.  We are far from each other because my husband's visa was cancelled.  When separated, we starting fighting and misunderstand each other all the time; we argue and sometimes my husband says "talaaq" to me or he says "I divorce you three times."

So my question is: Does he need to visit a court to file for divorce?

By saying "talaaq", does it mean that I'm legally divorced?  As in, right now I can marry again, even he doesn't file a divorce for me?

Answer (score 2):

No need to visit any court. For shariah purpose divorce occurs by husband just saying "I divorce you" to his wife. After divorce you need to wait for iddah to complete before you can marry again.